# Normalize numbers to 100 using D3 range?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, normalization

I'm trying to take a given array of numbers and normalize them be 0-100.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  Someone please help me find my dumb mistake?

```
var arr = [6345, 45678, 34572, 59867, 23517, 20938, 9872345, 2986];

arr.sort();

var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, arr[0]]).range([0, 100]);

for ( var i in arr ){
    console.log(scale(arr[i]));
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Troop4Christ/8jzFq/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
var max = d3.max(arr);
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, max]).range([0, 100]);
```

Comment: Doh! yeah.. I just noticed that I needed arr.sort().reverse()

I was feeding in the lowest value for the top boundary of the domain..

I knew it was something simple (facepalm)

Thanks!